# Tox over Tor won't come online

Tags: proxy, tor, privacy, tox

I've recently installed toxic (tox-based terminal chat client) and am attempting to route it through Tor for extra privacy. I followed [this](https://wiki.tox.chat/users/tox_over_tor_tot) tutorial for installing the tor service. But, when I try and start toxic with forced TCP going through the localhost Tor proxy, toxic will start, but will remain offline.

How can I fix this? I can provide screenshots/configurations if necessary, I really just want to get this up and running.

Comment: How exactly are you running it? `torify toxic`?

Comment: `toxic --force-tcp --SOCKS5-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050`

Comment: When I run `torify toxic` I get this error: `Toxic session aborted with error code 3 (tox_new returned fatal error)`